# HTTP Status 404 – Not Found during hello world

Tags: java, http, servlets, web-applications

Im the beginner at web apps. 
I tried to run the first application, but error occured.
I copied everything from the book, there everything works, at my place not...typically. I have been looking for hours for solution. Couldn't find.
I'm using 10.02 java, Apache Tomcat/9.0.12 and IntelliJ.

Here how my files structure looks like:

[image: ent]

That is how configuration of Tomcat looks like:

[image]

**HomeController**

```
package com.packt.webstore.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String welcome(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", "Hello");
        model.addAttribute("tagline", "In the internet");
        return "welcome";
    }
}
```

**welcome.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Witaj</title>
</head>
<body>
<section>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            <h1> ${greeting} </h1>
            <p> ${tagline} </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

**DefaultServletservlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.packt.webstore"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>DefaultServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DefaultServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.packt</groupId>
    <artifactId>webstore</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build><plugins><plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin></plugins></build>
</project>
```

**Here is stacktrace:**

```
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\apache-tomcat-9.0.12\bin\catalina.bat run
[2018-09-20 04:30:29,254] Artifact webstore:war exploded: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\Admin\.IntelliJIdea2018.2\system\tomcat\Unnamed_webstore_2"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\apache-tomcat-9.0.12"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\apache-tomcat-9.0.12\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\apache-tomcat-9.0.12\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\apache-tomcat-9.0.12\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
20-Sep-2018 16:30:31.591 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/9.0.12
20-Sep-2018 16:30:31.596 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Sep 4 2018 22:13:41 UTC
20-Sep-2018 16:30:31.596 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         9.0.12.0
20-Sep-2018 16:30:31.596 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 7
20-Sep-2018 16:30:31.597 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            6.1
20-Sep-2018 16:30:31.597 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
20-Sep-2018 16:30:31.597 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2
20-Sep-2018 16:30:31.597 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           10.0.2+13
20-Sep-2018 16:30:31.598 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            "Oracle Corporation"
20-Sep-2018 16:30:31.598 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\Admin\.IntelliJIdea2018.2\system\tomcat\Unnamed_webstore_2
20-Sep-2018 16:30:31.598 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\apache-tomcat-9.0.12
20-Sep-2018 16:30:31.603 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
20-Sep-2018 16:30:31.603 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
20-Sep-2018 16:30:31.604 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
20-Sep-2018 16:30:31.604 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\Admin\.IntelliJIdea2018.2\system\tomcat\Unnamed_webstore_2\conf\logging.properties
20-Sep-2018 16:30:31.604 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
20-Sep-2018 16:30:31.604 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
20-Sep-2018 16:30:31.604 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
20-Sep-2018 16:30:31.605 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
20-Sep-2018 16:30:31.605 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
20-Sep-2018 16:30:31.605 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
20-Sep-2018 16:30:31.605 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
20-Sep-2018 16:30:31.606 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
20-Sep-2018 16:30:31.606 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
20-Sep-2018 16:30:31.606 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Admin\.IntelliJIdea2018.2\system\tomcat\Unnamed_webstore_2
20-Sep-2018 16:30:31.606 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\apache-tomcat-9.0.12
20-Sep-2018 16:30:31.606 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\apache-tomcat-9.0.12\temp
20-Sep-2018 16:30:31.607 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;.]
20-Sep-2018 16:30:31.690 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
20-Sep-2018 16:30:31.719 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
20-Sep-2018 16:30:31.732 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
20-Sep-2018 16:30:31.735 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
20-Sep-2018 16:30:31.736 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 949 ms
20-Sep-2018 16:30:31.880 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
20-Sep-2018 16:30:31.880 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.12
20-Sep-2018 16:30:31.909 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
20-Sep-2018 16:30:31.930 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
20-Sep-2018 16:30:31.937 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 200 ms
Connected to server
[2018-09-20 04:30:32,156] Artifact webstore:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
[2018-09-20 04:30:33,434] Artifact webstore:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2018-09-20 04:30:33,434] Artifact webstore:war exploded: Deploy took 1 278 milliseconds
20-Sep-2018 16:30:41.920 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\apache-tomcat-9.0.12\webapps\manager]
20-Sep-2018 16:30:42.028 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\apache-tomcat-9.0.12\webapps\manager] has finished in [108] ms
```

And that's how page looks like: (I tried both `http://localhost:8080/` and `http://localhost:8080/webstore`
[image]`

///EDIT
Updated project according to @Ce7 's post .

Project Structure

[image]

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.packt</groupId>
    <artifactId>webstore</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>DefaultServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/DefaultServlet-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DefaultServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**Stacktrace**
(i had to paste it on pastebin, because question is too long)

https://pastebin.com/SS0uVKjU

Page

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Config you pom properly, your current configuration is creating jar file, instead of war, and you don't have maven war plugin to put your web resource (jsp, web.xml, etc) into the war file.

   ```
          <groupId>com.packt</groupId>
          <artifactId>webstore</artifactId>
          <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version> 
          <packaging>war</packaging>

       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>2.6</version>
           <configuration>
               <warSourceDirectory>webapp</warSourceDirectory>
               <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
           </configuration>
       </plugin>
   ```
2. Put your WEB-INF folder under a root folder, for example webapp/WEB-INF, here webapp folder is in same level as src folder
   [image]
3. Rename your DefaultServeletservlet.xml to

> DefaultServelet-servlet.xml

4. Modify web.xml file to config DefaultServlet.

   ```
    <servlet>
         ...
         <init-param>
          <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
          <param-value>/WEB-INF/DefaultServlet-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
   ```
5. After all of this, deploy it, then you should see something like this:
   [image]

Comment: It is worse than it was. I've updated my question. Check it out.

Comment: maven is looking for war resource in a directory, in our case, webapp folder. So you need to create it in root level, and put the WEB-INF folder.

Comment: It works...finally. But I've got question about 4. point. Why do i need that and what it does?

Comment: It's an init parameter we use to config the servlet,  `contextConfigLocation` param tells the servlet where to find context configuration, the servlet will use the configuration file (DeafaultServlet-servlet.xml) to create web application context. If you check the source code, it's a class field in the parent class of `DispatcherServlet`, FrameworkServlet. And you should be able to see how it's used.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the above is that you have named your `servlet configuration file` as `DefaultServletservlet.xml`.

Instead you should `rename` it as `DefaultServlet-servlet.xml`. While checking for the `xml configuration` spring matches the filename with `-servlet` as a suffix. As it is not able to find `DefaultServlet-servlet.xml`, hence the error.

Comment: nothing changed. I renamed `DefaultServletservlet.xml` to `DefaultServlet-servlet.xml`

Comment: but u were right `-` was missing. Unfortunately, still doesn't work :(

Comment: Strange. It's working on my machine. Can you try cleaning tomcat  working directory and build again? And check if the webstore.war is created in the directory.

Comment: I've cleaned tomcat working directory. Still doesn't work. `.war` file should appear at at artifacts? I've edited my question in which I added updated project stucture.

Comment: .war file should appear in the target folder after you run maven package